# error calling cvEigenDecomposite and cvCreateMat functions in opencv using Opencv in java

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I have been trying to implement face recognition in java using Opencv and Javacv libraries in eclipse. I searched for coding examples on this topic and i found a link showing that. But my problem is that there are functions like cvEigenDecomposite and cvCreateMat used in the example code. But **cvEigenDecomposite** generates error and also the function **cvCreateMat** produces error when taking CV_32FC1 as the last parameter. Does anyone have any idea on this? Has there been an alternative developed for this in the recent versions or am I missing something?

Please help me find an answer to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the link or some of code where those functions are called. Those look like legacy opencv functions, there are usually recent alternatives.

Comment: Oh sorry missed mentioning the link. Its in http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/FaceRecognition.java?r=39d251265715f7204573d0b68868c7749fee84d6. I also did import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_legacy.*; yet the errors on the functions persist please let me know the solution to this. Thank You.

Comment: I am so sorry. It worked completely fine while importing the legacy function. I had just put some of the parameters wrongly. :)

Comment: For those who stumble onto this question, do you mind explaining what you mean by "some parameters"?